# Pipelining internally from one function to another

Tags: powershell

I have a module which has the following two functions, which are almost identical:

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Retrieves a VApp from VCloud.
#>
Function Get-VApp
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Xml.XmlElement])]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Xml.XmlElement] $Session,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string[]] $VAppName
    )
    Begin {
        [System.Xml.XmlElement] $queryList = $Session.GetQueryList();
        [System.Xml.XmlElement[]] $vAppRecords = $queryList.GetVAppsByRecords().VAppRecord;
    }
    Process {
        ForEach ($VAN in $VAppName)
        {
            $vAppRecords |
            Where-Object { $_.name -eq $VAN } |
            ForEach-Object { $_.Get(); }
        }
    }
    End
    {
        #
    }
}
```

and

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Retrieves a VAppRecord from VCloud.
#>
Function Get-VAppRecord
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Xml.XmlElement])]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Xml.XmlElement] $Session,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string[]] $VAppName
    )
    Begin {
        [System.Xml.XmlElement] $queryList = $Session.GetQueryList();
        [System.Xml.XmlElement[]] $vAppRecords = $queryList.GetVAppsByRecords().VAppRecord;
    }
    Process {
        ForEach ($VAN in $VAppName)
        {
            $vAppRecords |
            Where-Object { $_.name -eq $VAN } |
            ForEach-Object { $_; }
        }
    }
    End
    {
        #
    }
}
```

Essentially, Get-VApp is like Get-VAppRecord, except that the former calls a Get() method on the returned object. This seems wasteful. If I wasn't bothering with pipelines, it would be easy:

```
Function Get-VApp
{
        [CmdletBinding()]
        [OutputType([System.Xml.XmlElement])]
        Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [System.Xml.XmlElement] $Session,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string[]] $VAppName
        )
    Get-VAppRecord $Session $VAppName |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Get();
    }
}
```

But obviously the pipeline messes things up. I don't call the code in the Begin block multiple times for efficiency, and I would like to find a way to "play nice" with the pipeline without having to batch up records.

Comment: Why do you need the `ForEach-Object` calls?

Comment: To be explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`SteppablePipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.steppablepipeline) class is designed for wrapping pipeline-enabled commands without messing up their pipeline support.

You don't even need to know how to set it up, [`ProxyCommand.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.proxycommand.create) will generate the scaffolding for it!

So let's start out by creating a proxy function for `Get-VAppRecord`:

```
$GetVAppRecordCommand = Get-Command Get-VAppRecord
$GetVAppRecordCommandMetadata = [System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata]::new($GetVAppRecordCommand)

# returns the body of the new proxy functions
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($GetVAppRecordCommandMetadata)
```

... and then we just need to add the `Get()` call in the `process` block of it:

```
function Get-VApp {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [System.Xml.XmlElement]
        ${Session},

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]]
        ${VAppName})

    begin
    {
        try {
            $outBuffer = $null
            if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
            {
                $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
            }
            $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Get-VAppRecord', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Function)
            $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
            $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline()
            $steppablePipeline.Begin($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) # Many examples use $PSCmdlet; however setting this ensures that $steppablePipeline.Process() returns the output of the inner function.
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    process
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.Process($_) |ForEach-Object {
                # call Get() on the record
                $_.Get()
            }
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    end
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.End()
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like what I was looking for. I'll check it out when I get home. What is the minimum PowerShell version?

Comment: Ok - I've tried the code, but the problem is that the inner function is returning its output directly to the outer function's pipeline, and the output of the Process() function is an empty array.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw It's not entirely clear to me what you mean by that. What effects are you seeing? Getting any errors?

Comment: There are no errors. When I step through the code, when I get to the Process() method, I see that the Process block is called. When an item is sent to the pipeline, it is immediately sent to the host, and Process() does not return any items.

Comment: I've done more research on this, and I am yet to find an example of SteppablePipeline which doesn't use the boiler plate code above. In all the examples I saw the purpose is to essentially redefine an existing command, and there is no conditional branching in the Process block. The only way I can think of doing what I want is to send the output back through a script level variable. This is a crappy way to do it, because now I have to detect how the inner function is being called, and handle it differently depending on whether it being called via the outer function or directly.

Comment: After some perusal of some terrible documentation, and a lot of experimentation, I found out that the missing bit of information is that the Begin() method should be given a boolean argument. In particular, the value should be $MyInvocation.ExpectingInput. This copes with the outer function taking values via the pipeline or via specified arguments.