# Reusable SteppablePipeline code breaks randomly

Tags: powershell

I have been writing a Powershell library which uses a lot of wrappers around one or two functions. Thanks to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847158/pipelining-internally-from-one-function-to-another), I discovered that I could use the GetSteppablePipeline() method to do the wrapping. However, I would like to be able to generalize this code. Googling the command, I discovered that there are only one or two samples which have been copied to death, but no single function. So I tried it. It seemed to work at first, and the sample below is roughly what I created first. But when I started to use the code in anger, it just seemed to break all over the place.

If you run the below straight through, it works ok. But if you put in any breakpoints in the ISE, it will break with errors like "Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'function' does not exist.". If you incorporate the code into any other script, it will also break with seemingly incomprehensible errors (for instance, Where-Object not being recognised as a Cmdlet).

```
Function CreateSteppablePipeline
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]
        $InnerFunctionName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]
        $OuterPSBoundParameters,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [System.Management.Automation.EngineIntrinsics]
        $OuterExecutionContext,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 3)]
        [System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo]
        $OuterMyInvocation
    )
    $outBuffer = $null
    if ($OuterPSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
    {
        $OuterPSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
    }
    [System.Management.Automation.FunctionInfo] $wrappedCmd = $OuterExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand($InnerFunctionName, [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Function);
    [ScriptBlock] $scriptCmd = { & $wrappedCmd @OuterPSBoundParameters };
    [System.Management.Automation.SteppablePipeline] $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($OuterMyInvocation.CommandOrigin);
    $steppablePipeline.Begin($OuterMyInvocation.ExpectingInput);
    $steppablePipeline;
}

Function Inner
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string] $ExParam,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]] $Value
    )
    Begin {
        [int] $i = 0;
    }
    Process {
        $i++;
        ForEach ($myValue In $Value)
        {
            $myValue;
        }
    }
    End {
        $i;
        $ExParam;
    }
}

Function Outer
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string] $ExParam,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]] $Value
    )
    Begin {
        [System.Management.Automation.SteppablePipeline] $steppablePipeline = CreateSteppablePipeline "Inner" $PSBoundParameters $ExecutionContext $MyInvocation;
    }
    Process {
        $steppablePipeline.Process($_) |
        ForEach-Object {
            $_ + " : Pipelined";
        }
    }
    End {
        $steppablePipeline.End()
    }   
}

Outer -ExParam 22 "Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7"
"Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6","Name7" | Outer -ExParam 22
```

It has probably to do with scoping (a problem I have come across a number of times in scripts). I tried moving parts of the CreateSteppablePipeline() function between the calling and function scope, but with no luck.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks - that worked. It didn't occur to me to dot source a "private" function inside a PowerShell library file. Just for interest - how did it occur to you that this would be the answer?

Comment: In unrelated incident I happens to learn that `SteppablePipeline` have this kind of issues if it used not in the scope where it was created. I can not name exact condition for this misbehavior though.