# Is there a way to hook into an internal PowerShell function event?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to hook into an internal PowerShell function event?  Specifically looking to add code to the Copy-Item function when the call is started, finishes or errors out.  I know I can just override the function but I was trying to avoid rewriting that code.

How would you even get what events are available for Copy-Item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [proxy functions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/):

```bsh
$MetaData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData (Get-Command  Copy-Item)
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($MetaData)
```

It does require writing some code, of course, but it's certainly easier than recompiling a core DLL.

Answer (score 1):

It's written in C#, but you can get to it.

Run

```
Get-Command -Name Copy-Item | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DLL
```

to find the DLL it's part of.

The use dotpeek https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/ and open the DLL there.

Finally navigate to "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands", expand it then double click CopyItemCommand and you'll get the source code.

EDIT: I realize that's not quite an answer to your question. But afaik the only way to reuse the code is to use that source code to compile a new DLL and load that as a module in PowerShell overwriting the original cmdlet.

Comment: `dotpeek` (or `ILSpy`/`dnSpy`) or similar is great for figuring out exactly what is going on under the covers, but the only real available support for actually hooking cmdlets at runtime is by [proxying them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51847158/pipelining-internally-from-one-function-to-another/51847464#51847464)

Comment: Both answers were good.  I didn’t find any events exposed for copy-item so ended up using the other suggestion of using a proxy function and add my own content to it.  The dotpeek was interesting and will make use of it in the future - thanks!